# Shopify header not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, shopify, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm using Mr Parker theme.
The theme is working perfectly on chrome and MS Edge, but when I open in Mozilla Firefox, I'm unable to click on "search", "cart" and "account", but the currency changer is working fine.
Please help me out to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: i think you should message theme support about that.

Comment: In the latest firefox is working well, you need to check the version and make sure all is to its latest.

Comment: I tried to contact them but no response is coming from their side.

Comment: I'm using the latest version